# Ant MailLogger doesn't send email

Tags: email, ant, logging, postfix-mta

I run ant like this in order to have an email with the log of the build : ant deployDB -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger

Here or my properties :

```
MailLogger.mailhost         = myhost
MailLogger.port=25
MailLogger.user             = myuser
MailLogger.password         = mypassword
MailLogger.from             = myfromemail
MailLogger.failure.to       = myreceipeemail
MailLogger.success.to       = myreceipeemail
MailLogger.failure.subject=[DRUPAL][MEP] ${TODAY} - Failure
MailLogger.success.subject=[DRUPAL][MEP] ${TODAY} - Success
```

I don't receive the email at the end of the build and I have no error message. When I look in /var/log/mail.info there is no log about the email which was supposed to be sent.

I tried my postfix SMTP server with a simple java program, with exactly the same params and I do receive an email, so I guess my SMTP server is working fine.

Comment: Could you copy the relevant lines?

Comment: Are mail.jar and activtion.jar on ant classpath ? see = http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies

Comment: Yeah, stupid me, I forgot to add mail.jar. Now it's working fine without activation.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has never been marked as resolved I'm just copying what Rebse said in comment.

It was a classpath issue, mail.jar wasn't in it.

Thanks Rebse!